# Xcode Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64 Kudan iOS

Tags: ios, xcode, augmented-reality, kudan

I have downloaded [Kudan](https://www.xlsoft.com/en/products/kudan/?utm_source=google&utm_medium=adwords&utm_campaign=cp01) AR SDK for iOS and trying to run the [samples](https://github.com/kudan-eu/Enhanced-Samples-iOS) on my Xcode 9.2. Every time I find this error:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_AROcclusionMaterial", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in AnimationOcclusionViewController.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_ARTextureMaterial", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in TextureMorphingViewController.o
      objc-class-ref in ThreeDModelOnMarkerViewController.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_ARColourMaterial", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in TextureMorphingViewController.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_ARExtractedCameraTexture", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in TextureMorphingViewController.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_ARVector3", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in ComplexAnimationViewController.o
      objc-class-ref in MarkerlessTrackingViewController.o
      objc-class-ref in AnimationOcclusionViewController.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_ARModelImporter", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in ComplexAnimationViewController.o
      objc-class-ref in MarkerlessTrackingViewController.o
      objc-class-ref in TextureMorphingViewController.o
      objc-class-ref in ThreeDModelOnMarkerViewController.o
      objc-class-ref in AnimationOcclusionViewController.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_ARLightMaterial", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in ComplexAnimationViewController.o
      objc-class-ref in MarkerlessTrackingViewController.o
      objc-class-ref in AnimationOcclusionViewController.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_ARNode", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in MarkerlessTrackingViewController.o
      objc-class-ref in TextureMorphingViewController.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_ARAPIKey", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in AppDelegate.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_ARCameraViewController", referenced from:
      _OBJC_CLASS_$_VideoOnTextureViewController in VideoOnTextureViewController.o
      _OBJC_CLASS_$_ComplexAnimationViewController in ComplexAnimationViewController.o
      _OBJC_CLASS_$_MarkerlessTrackingViewController in MarkerlessTrackingViewController.o
      _OBJC_CLASS_$_TextureMorphingViewController in TextureMorphingViewController.o
      _OBJC_CLASS_$_ThreeDModelOnMarkerViewController in ThreeDModelOnMarkerViewController.o
      _OBJC_CLASS_$_AlphaVideoOnTextureViewController in AlphaVideoOnTextureViewController.o
      _OBJC_CLASS_$_AnimationOcclusionViewController in AnimationOcclusionViewController.o
      ...
  "_OBJC_METACLASS_$_ARCameraViewController", referenced from:
      _OBJC_METACLASS_$_VideoOnTextureViewController in VideoOnTextureViewController.o
      _OBJC_METACLASS_$_ComplexAnimationViewController in ComplexAnimationViewController.o
      _OBJC_METACLASS_$_MarkerlessTrackingViewController in MarkerlessTrackingViewController.o
      _OBJC_METACLASS_$_TextureMorphingViewController in TextureMorphingViewController.o
      _OBJC_METACLASS_$_ThreeDModelOnMarkerViewController in ThreeDModelOnMarkerViewController.o
      _OBJC_METACLASS_$_AlphaVideoOnTextureViewController in AlphaVideoOnTextureViewController.o
      _OBJC_METACLASS_$_AnimationOcclusionViewController in AnimationOcclusionViewController.o
      ...
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_ARTexture", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in ComplexAnimationViewController.o
      objc-class-ref in MarkerlessTrackingViewController.o
      objc-class-ref in ThreeDModelOnMarkerViewController.o
      objc-class-ref in AnimationOcclusionViewController.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_ARImageNode", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in MarkerlessTrackingViewController.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_ARImageTrackable", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in VideoOnTextureViewController.o
      objc-class-ref in ComplexAnimationViewController.o
      objc-class-ref in TextureMorphingViewController.o
      objc-class-ref in ThreeDModelOnMarkerViewController.o
      objc-class-ref in AlphaVideoOnTextureViewController.o
      objc-class-ref in AnimationOcclusionViewController.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_ARGyroPlaceManager", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in MarkerlessTrackingViewController.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_ARAlphaVideoNode", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in AlphaVideoOnTextureViewController.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_ARRenderer", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in MarkerlessTrackingViewController.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_ARArbiTrackerManager", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in MarkerlessTrackingViewController.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_ARImageTrackerManager", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in VideoOnTextureViewController.o
      objc-class-ref in ComplexAnimationViewController.o
      objc-class-ref in TextureMorphingViewController.o
      objc-class-ref in ThreeDModelOnMarkerViewController.o
      objc-class-ref in AlphaVideoOnTextureViewController.o
      objc-class-ref in AnimationOcclusionViewController.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_ARVideoNode", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in VideoOnTextureViewController.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I have tried to add x86_64 to the Valid Architecture but it didn't work. I have also tried to change the deployment target to 9.0 but it didn't work also.

The library is added correctly to the project and also the required libc++.tbd is there.

What is the problem then ?

Comment: Check if that file is included in Build Phases -> Compiled Sources